# How to name and search for DOM elements created inside jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

guys. I'm developing a jQuery plugin that wraps an element inside a container. So, this line:

```
$azureRectangle.container(); //azureRectangle is only an empty div
```

Produces this:

[image]

The container is composed with many new divs. Well, here is my doubt: How should I name or identify those created divs? Should I use a data attribute or an invented id or name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are several policies for that. You certainly can use either 'data' or 'rev' attributes, but then you might have difficulties when trying to select a specific container element.

Usually, though, wrapper (and replacer) plugins work with elements with `id` attribute set, so they can generate a corresponding `id` for the elements they create. For example:

```
$.fn.somePlugin = function(someId) {
  var somePluginId = 'some-plugin-' + someId;
  ...
}
```

This allows both grapping all items (with `'[id^="some-plugin-"]'` selector) and each specific one (having an `id` of element which was involved in its creation).

The same policy, of course, can be applied when more then one new element should be created; you just have to use several specific prefixes for these.